# Sanskrit font cannot be found

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I tried to generate a pdf file from the following document using pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX on Windows 7 (MiKTex 2.9). pdfLaTeX responded that I need to use XeLaTeX. When I used XeLaTeX, it said the the font `sanskrit` cannot be found. I tried other fonts such as `samarkan`, `Bengali`,`Gurmukhi`, `Gujarati` from the `Devanagari` font set. Could someone please help me to resolve this issue as well as find the way to run it under pdfLaTeX?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2.0cm,bottom=2.0cm,left=0.5cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[iso]{datetime}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\devtransl[Mapping=DevRom]{Times New Roman}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{0.5pt}
\chead{\textbf{\huge{Inform}}}
\lhead{\textbf{Test1}}
\rhead{\textbf{\normalsize{Sets}}}
\rfoot{\today \hspace{0.5pt} \currenttime}
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}\lfoot{Some}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
\tablehead
{
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{p{24.5mm}}{\textbf{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{ग्रोस वोलयूम}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\textbf{नेट वाल्यूम}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\textbf{लेवल}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\textbf{तापमान}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\centering{\textbf{ऊलाज}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{42mm}}{\centering{\textbf{लास्ट अपडेटड}}}\\

& \multicolumn{1}{p{24.5mm}}{\centering{\textbf{गैलन}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\centering{\textbf{गैलन}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\textbf{सेन्टीमीटर}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\centering{\textbf{सेन्टीग्रेड}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\centering{\textbf{गैलन}}} & \\
\toprule
}

\begin{supertabular}{p{35mm}*{6}{r}}
\\ \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf {3001}}\\\\
\textbf{टेंक  2} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{SET1}\\
PROD 2& \multicolumn{6}{l}{(4,011 अधिकतम)}\\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{प्रोडक्ट}} & 2,495.40 & 2,479.66 & 145.55 & 20.53 & 1,313.07 & 19/04/2012 15:00:23 \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Water}} & 1.79 & & 1.00 & & & \\\\ 
\textbf{टेंक  3} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{SET2}\\
PROD 3& \multicolumn{6}{l}{(4,011 अधिकतम)}\\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{प्रोडक्ट}} & 2,593.08 & 2,578.51 & 150.40 & 20.01 & 1,213.86 & 19/04/2012 15:00:23 \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{SET3}} & 3.32 & & 1.51 & & & \\\\ 
\toprule[2pt]\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thanks for posting a full document. Please follow my advice at [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) to reduce your code to a so-called *Minimal Working Example*. As it is now, most of the things in your code are entirely unrelated to your actual problem. By making problems abstract and minimal, we try to make them maximally relevant and helpful for other users who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

there are a lot of Times fonts and sanskrit. You have to look into your system for the correct names, eg for Linux

```
fc-list | grep Sanskrit
```

However, you have to switch to the sanskrit font

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TimesNewRomanPSStd-Regular}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Sanskrit2003}
\newfontfamily\devtransl[Mapping=DevRom]{TimesNewRomanPSStd-Regular}

\usepackage{booktabs,supertabular}

\begin{document}
\tablehead
{
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{p{24.5mm}}{\devanagarifont\textbf{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{ग्रोस वोलयूम}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\devanagarifont\textbf{नेट वाल्यूम}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\devanagarifont\textbf{लेवल}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\devanagarifont\textbf{तापमान}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\centering{\devanagarifont\textbf{ऊलाज}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{42mm}}{\centering{\devanagarifont\textbf{लास्ट अपडेटड}}}\\

& \multicolumn{1}{p{24.5mm}}{\centering{\devanagarifont\textbf{गैलन}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\centering{\devanagarifont\textbf{गैलन}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\devanagarifont\textbf{सेन्टीमीटर}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\devanagarifont\centering{\textbf{सेन्टीग्रेड}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\devanagarifont\centering{\textbf{गैलन}}} & \\
\toprule
}

\begin{supertabular}{p{35mm}*{6}{r}}
\\ \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf {3001}}\\\\
\devanagarifont\textbf{टेंक  2} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{SET1}\\
PROD 2& \multicolumn{6}{l}{(4,011 \devanagarifont अधिकतम)}\\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\devanagarifont\textbf{प्रोडक्ट}} & 2,495.40 & 2,479.66 & 145.55 & 20.53 & 1,313.07 & 19/04/2012 15:00:23 \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Water}} & 1.79 & & 1.00 & & & \\\\ 
\devanagarifont\textbf{टेंक  3} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{SET2}\\
PROD 3& \multicolumn{6}{l}{(4,011\devanagarifont  अधिकतम)}\\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\devanagarifont\textbf{प्रोडक्ट}} & 2,593.08 & 2,578.51 & 150.40 & 20.01 & 1,213.86 & 19/04/2012 15:00:23 \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{SET3}} & 3.32 & & 1.51 & & & \\\\ 
\toprule[2pt]\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Herbert, thank you for your response. I tried the console command in my Windows 7 and returns nothing. Do you know how can I install such font or if there is another font that I can use in this family? Also, is there a way to generate the pdf document by using pdfLatex instead of XeLatex?  Thanks again for your help

Comment: Also I tried your example and got: "TimesNewRomanPSStd-Regular" cannot be found. Please help. Thank you

Comment: As I wrote, there are a _lot_ of different Times New Roman. That one is installed in my system and in your it maybe another one. You can have a look into the font list.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that Latex has a different set of fonts as the host Operating System, at least for Windows. However it does not, it uses the same fonts as the Operating System. In the above problem and after the suggestion from Herbert, I installed the Sanskrit 2003 font in Windows from http://www.omkarananda-ashram.org/Sanskrit/itranslator2003.htm#dls and it worked:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Sanskrit 2003}
\newfontfamily\devtransl[Mapping=DevRom]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{booktabs,supertabular}

\begin{document}
\tablehead
{
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{p{24.5mm}}{\devanagarifont\textbf{\foreignlanguage{hindi}{ग्रोस वोलयूम}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\devanagarifont\textbf{नेट वाल्यूम}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\devanagarifont\textbf{लेवल}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\devanagarifont\textbf{तापमान}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\centering{\devanagarifont\textbf{ऊलाज}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{42mm}}{\centering{\devanagarifont\textbf{लास्ट अपडेटड}}}\\

& \multicolumn{1}{p{24.5mm}}{\centering{\devanagarifont\textbf{गैलन}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\centering{\devanagarifont\textbf{गैलन}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\devanagarifont\textbf{सेन्टीमीटर}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\devanagarifont\centering{\textbf{सेन्टीग्रेड}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\devanagarifont\centering{\textbf{गैलन}}} & \\
\toprule
}

\begin{supertabular}{p{35mm}*{6}{r}}
\\ \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf {3001}}\\\\
\devanagarifont\textbf{टेंक  2} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{SET1}\\
PROD 2& \multicolumn{6}{l}{(4,011 \devanagarifont अधिकतम)}\\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\devanagarifont\textbf{प्रोडक्ट}} & 2,495.40 & 2,479.66 & 145.55 & 20.53 & 1,313.07 & 19/04/2012 15:00:23 \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Water}} & 1.79 & & 1.00 & & & \\\\ 
\devanagarifont\textbf{टेंक  3} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{SET2}\\
PROD 3& \multicolumn{6}{l}{(4,011\devanagarifont  अधिकतम)}\\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\devanagarifont\textbf{प्रोडक्ट}} & 2,593.08 & 2,578.51 & 150.40 & 20.01 & 1,213.86 & 19/04/2012 15:00:23 \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{SET3}} & 3.32 & & 1.51 & & & \\\\ 
\toprule[2pt]\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a tip: if you indent the code by four spaces, it will shown as code. I did just that on your code, see above. Regarding the fonts: pdflatex does use its own set of Type 1 fonts, while XeteX and LuaLaTeX can use the system fonts.